I am not getting desired output using this auto template in Emacs verilog-mode, i am using this from veripool.org . What mistakes i am doing in code?
I have 1 top module and 1 submodule and i want to autoinst using auto template and regex, my modules are:-
     module submodule (
         input [31:0] in_data,
         input in_valid,
         output in_ready
         output [31:0] out_data,
         output out_valid,
         input out_ready,
         input [3:0] in_id,
         output [1:0] out_resp,
         input clk,
         input rstn
     );
     //logic written here
     endmodule

     module top (
         input [31:0] bus_data,
         input bus_valid,
         input bus_ready,
         output [31:0] ctrl_data,
         output ctrl_valid,
         input ctrl_ready,
         input [3:0] bus_id,
         output [1:0] ctrl_resp,
         input clk,
         input rstn
     );
     /*
     submodule AUTO_TEMPLATE (
         .in@_\(.*\) (bus_\1of\2),
         .out@_(.*\) (ctrl_\1of\2),
         );
     */
     submodule u_submodule (
         /*AUTOINST*/
     );

I am using the below command in terminal to run the code
emacs --batch top.v --debug-init -f verilog-batch-inject-auto

After running this command, normal auto-inst is happening not the templated one.

The following works, but you should try reading the manual:
https://veripool.org/verilog-mode/help/#verilog-auto-inst
module submodule (
                  input  [31:0] data_in,
                  input         valid_in,
                  output        ready_in
                  output [31:0] data_out,
                  output        valid_out,
                  input         ready_out,
                  input  [3:0]  id_in,
                  output [1:0]  resp_out,
                  input         clk,
                  input         rstn
                  );
   //logic written here
endmodule // submodule

module top (
            input  [31:0] bus_data,
            input         bus_valid,
            input         bus_ready,
            output [31:0] ctrl_data,
            output        ctrl_valid,
            input         ctrl_ready,
            input  [3:0]  bus_id,
            output [1:0]  ctrl_resp,
            input         clk,
            input         rstn
            );
   /* submodule AUTO_TEMPLATE (
    .\(.*_in\) (bus_\1),
    .\(.*_out\) (ctrl_\1),
    );
    */
   submodule u_submodule (/*AUTOINST*/
                          // Outputs
                          .ready_in             (bus_ready_in),  // Templated
                          .data_out             (ctrl_data_out), // Templated
                          .valid_out            (ctrl_valid_out), // Templated
                          .resp_out             (ctrl_resp_out), // Templated
                          // Inputs
                          .data_in              (bus_data_in),   // Templated
                          .valid_in             (bus_valid_in),  // Templated
                          .ready_out            (ctrl_ready_out), // Templated
                          .id_in                (bus_id_in),     // Templated
                          .clk                  (clk),
                          .rstn                 (rstn));

endmodule // top

Your question above is missing details, so I assumed you're making the same question as in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79111072/how-to-use-regex-in-auto-instantiation-of-emacs-verilog-mode-in-auto-template
edit:
also, you should be using verilog-batch-auto in batch mode, NOT verilog-batch-inject-auto
